# How to clear textbox value when checkbox got unchecked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have one datatable (created using jQuery) whose first column contains checkboxes and last column contains textboxes. Since textbox and checkbox are created dynamically, so they have same IDs and names which is as below:

```
   $('#statement-table').dataTable({
             "data": json,
             "dom": 't',
             "columns": [
                 {"data":""},
                 {"data": "statementCode"},
                 {"data": "dueDate"},
                 {"data": "statementBalance"},
                 {"data": ""}

             ],
             "columnDefs": [
                 {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4]},
                 {
                     'targets':   0,
                     'orderable': false,
                      'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                              return '<input type="checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" id="select-checkbox"/>';
                      }
                 },

                  {
                     'targets': 4,
                     'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                      return
                         '<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" name="text[]" class="payment" value=""/>';
                     }
                  }

             ],
             "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']],

         }); //End of datatable function
```

My requirement is to clear the textbox value when its corresponding checkbox got unchecked. I have written following jquery code but its not clearing textbox:

```
    $("input[name=payment-checkbox]").click(function () {
             $("table tr td input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                 var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
                    if (!ischecked) {
                         $(this).parent().next().find("input[type='text']").val("");
                    }
                    else
                   {
                        alert("do nothing");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: please include HTML mark , JS  in the OP..or better include a snippet. please check [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why are the IDs the same? Can't you add a numerical iterator to the end of each ID as  the textbox/checkbox combo is added to give them unique IDs?

Comment: give your form data

Comment: id should be different, could break your html

Comment: What if `checked` again ?

Comment: need your html form part

Comment: @Yash Capoor: how do we do that? I dont know that

Comment: @user3386779 : Added just now.

Comment: If I'm reading [the reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Types) correctly, the meta parameter for your render function contains row data. So you should be able to call `meta.row().index()` to get the index of the current row.

Using that, you can add that number to the `<input type="checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" id="select-checkbox'+meta.row().index()'"/>` to add a row ID to each checkbox/textbox as they're made. Sorry, can't try it out myself right now.

Comment: you can always use  jquery command closest

Comment: My bad. Looks like it should just be `meta.row`, not `meta.row().index()`.

Comment: @YashCapoor: Your solution is not working. When I checked the value of meta , its value is "undefined"

Answer (score 5):

> [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Use `name` attribute to select element

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $('[type="text"][name="' + this.name + '"]').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="name1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" checked>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name2" value="name1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" checked>
```

Comment: @ShubhangiGarg, How does that make a difference ?

Comment: I dont know why its not working for me..Just because all textboxes have same id?

Answer (score 0):

U could test on change and find the first text box

```
$('.test').change(function() {

    var checkboxINstance = $(this);
    if (!checkboxINstance.is(":checked"))
    {
      checkboxINstance.closest('tr').find("input[type=number]")[0].value= '';
    }       
});
```

see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/2b6e7v6t/1/

Comment: you do have jquery.. right? could you give more info. like composed html

Comment: I see it clearly now. you have type = number and not type is text. updated example